# Why my controller is not registered in below code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**My index file :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homingController">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Controller/homingController.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/angular-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="./css/icon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="./css/Main.css">
<title>Home Application</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<a href="#/monitor">about</a>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        template: "home",
        controller: 'homingController'
    })
        .when('/monitor', {
            template: "<p>{{firstName}}{{lastName}}</p>",
            controller: 'monitoringController'
        })
        .
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});

    mainApp.controller('monitoringController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
}])
```

My HomingController.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']); 
mainApp.controller('homingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
}])
```

My Home.html code :

```
<div ng-controller="homingController">
{{ lastName }} Hello
</div>
```

Now I am facing issue :

1) In homingController, if I add first line that is :

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

then it give me error :

angular.js:14328 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'homingController' is not registered.

1) In homingController, if I Dont add add first line that is :

```
var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

then it give me error :

angular.js:14328 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'homingController' is not registered.

thanks !!

Comment: Are you sure `homingController.js` is correctly included? Make sure its loaded.

Comment: can you make a plunker for this code?

Comment: Yes its added and I can see it in source as well

Comment: Plunkr not accessible for me due to resricted site

Comment: Have updated homingcontroller code as well

Comment: Codepen or Stackoverflow's tool?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee, is this ./Controller/ is correct path for homingController.js file?

Comment: Yes its correct path

Comment: My index.html is at base path and homingController is inside controller folder,,given path both ways but any of them not working

Comment: Can you provide the folder structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the module twice,

//Remove this line in your **`controller.js`** file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

///

```
app.controller("homingController", function($scope) {
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/HBu05ULrXNQgPZi5Hwq2?p=preview)**

Comment: this is giving error on console , Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee check the demo

Comment: thanks !!is it possible to have in codepen ? I dont have access of plunkr ,..Or you can paste here ?

Comment: thank you so much !!Whats in your homingcontroller..I am not able to redirect to there

Comment: its the same ! just alter as whatever you need1 mark if it helped

Comment: However, I am no more facing this controller error, but at same time, its not redirecting even

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156986/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-codewithcoffee).

Comment: it actually redirects, its just the content of both pages are same

Comment: Seems its restricted for my network as not able to access it !! Can you put some code in homingcontroller ? I have added router code in same html file and from there want to redirect to homingcontroller

Comment: Can I share my code at your email sajeetharan@outlook.com if you can have look ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the way you're adding your controller to your module.

Try Changing following line in homingController

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sajeetharan is right. you declared the module twice however deleting it in your controller.js makes an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` because you haven't declared the module before creating a controller

my suggestion is to make your main page into

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider) {

    // Define routes
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homingController'
    }).when('/monitor', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'monitoringController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'home'
    });

}
]);
```

since the app is defined first in controller.js