# Not able to load angular view

Tags: angularjs

I have index file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="./Controller/homingController.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/angular-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="./css/icon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="./css/Main.css">
<title>Home Application</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="navbar">
 <a href="#/home">Home</a>

<a href="#/monitor">about</a>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "home.html"
    , controller: "homingController"
});
});

app.controller('homingController', function ($scope, $http) {
alert ("Hello");
var url = "workingURL"; /// changed function to a simple string message to 
test
$scope.message = "Hello Liberals";
});
```

My View home.html

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
{{message}}
```

Neither its seems going into homingController and alerting Hello .

Nor its not loading view, infact when I debug its not going to controller. Is there anything I missing here ?

Comment: Are you missing `<div ng-view></div>` ?

Comment: I want to load home.html file content

Comment: That's what [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) is for. It places partials / templates (such as your home.html) into ng-view directive

Comment: As @AlekseySolovey said, `ngView` directive is missing in your HTML code. You have to place it inside your `ngApp` directive.

Comment: Have added it and updated code...still not wotking !! Any clues ?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804850/why-my-controller-is-not-registered-in-below-code please mark as answer if that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
Please refer following link:
```

you need to just seperate js code and html code

https://jsfiddle.net/ok9he9b9/2/